# Writing a bibliography

Tags: academic-writing, citations

In the formats I've seen for writing a bibliography, the author is always put first, and then the title. Are there some bibliographies where the title is put before the author?

Answer (score 4):

Chicago Style states that bibliographic list entries should be of the format:

Author last name, Author first name. *Title*. Location of press: Press name, Year Published

See here for more:
http://www.isr.bucknell.edu/img/assets/6535/chicago.pdf

A quick scan through my bookshelf, and I can't find a single bibliography that puts the title first before the author, so I would suggest this is not usual. However, there may be some styles out there that allow it. I imagine that, as long as you're consistent, it should be okay, but I would probably stick to the more well known format above.

Comment: Do note that this author-title format for the reflist is just one of two approaches used by *Chicago*; the style also supports author-date.

Answer (score 3):

Craig knows of no "title-author" citation styles; neither do I.

There is a pragmatic reason not to put the title first: since titles may be long, titles are often permitted to be shortened on second and subsequent mention.  To avoid the alphabetical ordering with title-author of the references to completely change from the full version to the short version, it would be necessary to forbid omission of words at the beginning of the title, which would be a very awkward constraint.  With author-title, the "jumping around" of references is much smaller.

So besides the absence of evidence, I think we have reason to believe there are no such styles.  Not that foolish construction of citation styles is unheard of, mind...

Comment: Who is that  person?

Answer (score 1):

The person or group for which you're writing the bibliography probably has a required style, so you should go by that.

I'm familiar with APA and MLA, and they both put the author first.  You need to have the first word in the bibliography consistent with the word you use in your in-text citations (or footnotes, if you're still doing those), and most styles that I'm aware of use the author's name in the citations.

If no author is available, things change a little, but it's pretty rare to find a truly reputable source of information for which you can't find an author or authors.

Comment: Comprehensive style guides do treat the case of the unknown author.  For instance, *Chicago*'s author-title style asks for title only to be used when citing, and for "Anonymous" to be used in place of the author's name in the reflist.

Answer (score 1):

**A SURVEY OF ONLINE BIBLIOGRAPHY GENERATORS SHOWS THAT “BLUEBOOOK” DOES NOT CITE THE AUTHOR FIRST**

There are several very good websites which will format your bibliography for you. Of the ones I quickly surveyed, [CiteThisForMe](http://www.citethisforme.com/us) seems to be the most comprehensive, with “Citation Machines” for the following citation styles: ACS, AMA, APA, Chicago, Harvard and MLA. A quick survey of all of these styles confirms that in a bibliography, the author is first in all of them. CiteThisForMe also has “Citation Generators” for APSA, ASA, Bluebook, IEEE, Turabian and Vancouver citation styles. All of these except for the Bluebook style use the author’s name first in the bibliography.

The [Bluebook style](http://www.citethisforme.com/us/styles/bluebook-citation-generator) is a legal citation style, which cites legal cases and statutes first, and then would cite authors only if a published source is used:

> There are many sources supported within the Bluebook including legal cases, Supreme Court cases and statutes. The way in which Bluebook citations are formatted depends on which type of source you are citing. A case citation, for example, includes the name of the case; the published sources in which it may be found, if any; a parenthetical that indicates a court and jurisdiction and the year or date of decision; and the subsequent history of case, if any. It may also include additional parenthetical information and prior history of the case.

A Bluebook legal case citation example (filed but not decided):

Sobieski v. Cook, 556 S.W.2d 701 (Tenn. 1999).